# How to take derivative of $2x^{2x^2}$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I know that to get the derivative of a power you multiply the coefficient by the power then adjust the power minus 1 e.g. $2x^3$ would be $6x^2$

I don't know how to handle when a function is a power e.g.$2x^{2x^2}$

How can I find the derivative here?

Comment: Take logarithm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, when you have a polynomial $f(x)$ raised to another polynomial $g(x)$, $f(x)^{g(x)}$; the trick is to simply rewrite it as $f(x)^{g(x)}=e^{ln(f(x))\cdot g(x)}$ since then you can apply the rule $(e^{h(x)})'=h'(x)\cdot e^{h(x)}$ where in this case $h(x)=ln(f(x))\cdot g(x)$. Maybe in terms of understanding it, it helps to find the derivative of the general case $f(x)^{g(x)}$?

Answer (score 2):

If expression is $2x^{(2x)^2}$
Let $y = 2x^{2x^2}$ and let $a = 2x$, then $\frac{da}{dx} = 2$
$\implies y = a^{a^2}$ Take $\log$ on both sides you get,
$\log{y} = a^2\log{a}$, Differentiate w.r.t $\;x\;$ you get
$\frac{dy}{dx}\left(\frac{1}{y}\right) = (\log{a})(2a)\frac{da}{dx} + a^2 \cfrac{\frac{da}{dx}}{a}$
$\implies \frac{dy}{dx} = (a^{a^2})(2a)(2\log{a} + 1)$.

Substitue $a = 2x$, you get $$\cfrac{dy}{dx} = (2x^{2x^2})(4x)(2\log{2x} + 1)$$

Answer (score 1):

when you have a power ($ 3^x ,x^x , your function ..... $) function
just do this:
$$2x^{2x^2}=2e^{ln(x)2x^2}$$
so:
$$f'(x)=2(2x+4xln(x))e^{ln(x)2x^2}$$

Answer (score 0):

the expression is the same as $\exp[2x^2\ln(2x)]$. and you can get the derivative of that expression useing the chain rule. and you will get $\exp[2x^2\ln(2x)]\cdot[4x\ln(2x)+2x]$ you can narrow the expression if you like to.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).